# Help! Table of Contents - odd behavior

Tags: table-of-contents, sharelatex

Requesting help. See link below.  I'm trying to figure out why within the table of contents it's putting the title and page number (I want to get rid of the "TEST BLANK 1----- 2" line.  I want to suppress this so it just starts with the executive summary.

Also, I'd like it to get rid of the TEST BLANK 1 that's ABOVE the table of contents header as well.

Essentially, it seems to be putting the content of \title in there - I want to get rid of the title on the page, and get rid of the title in the TOC.

Thank you!

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59ceb8ac478e804b755baad8

Comment: This is due to the `apa6.cls` and its option `man`. If you change this to `doc` it looks more like a traditional LaTex document.

Comment: By the way, sharing a project in this way allows anyone to edit it, thereby updating the project on-the-fly. Future visitors may not even see the original project and therefore not know what the issue is.

Comment: To avoid the issue brought up by the previous comment, we greatly prefer that questions be entirely self contained.  Include the necessary code in a minimal working example that you post here, not behind a link at sharelatex.